# Compiling C code in cmd prompt

Tags: c, cmd, windows-10

I use sublime text as my text editor and the cmd prompt to compile and run the code. The cmd prompt out of no where will no longer update the exe with the new code added to the program. Has anyone had this problem? It was working the other night and I have not changed any settings on the computer that would make this not work. Also the program has no errors

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Wingw... the command is a gcc command

Comment: gcc is the compiler, mingw is a port of gcc on Windows

Comment: All I know is I have not changed anything and it was working and now it's not... I will get the visual 2015 maybe the developer prompt will fix the issue I don't know

Comment: There's no information in your answer so no one will be able to answer. What's the command you used for compiling? Anyway mingw is not quite updated and has many bugs. Use mingw-w64 instead, it's much better

Comment: Ok I'll get wingw 64 as well.... I'm just trying to see if any one has had the same issue and fixed it. I honestly don't know how to 1. Show the issue or 2. Ask the question in the right manner for an answer to really be found... I am lost with this problem bc everything was working Monday night

Comment: If your problem is still unsolved, try to ask with step-by-step demonstration: 1) result of running `gcc` without parameters (test that compiler was found when run in `cmd`); 2) result of running `gcc` for simple hello-world program (perhaps it works for new program, so run the program to show output); 3) changes made in hello-world (e.g. output text "Hello, world" -> "Hello, GCC"); 4) compilation (2) of changed program (output of `gcc`) and result of running after that; 5) Your question.

Comment: I fixed this with the visual studios 2015 and the developer command prompt.  I do not know if I was missing something before but its working now so I am happy go lucky for now. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Visual Studio 2015 (or other edition) on Windows 10 and create source code file with `.c` extension, you can use `cl.exe`.

It is better to use Visual C++ developer command prompt (can be started from Start button).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>cl prog.c
```

Visual C++ developer command prompt provides environment settings like Path.
If you just run `cl.exe` without parameters you should see something like

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

This way is not for Mingw. But, perhaps, compiler is not limiting... so Visual Studio can work at the same PC. Just as an option

Comment: What is cl.exe?

Comment: Like I said I haven't had this problem till tonight

Comment: the compiler in MS Visual Studio

Comment: I will have to look into that